# Why, or why not, is $5^{log_3(n)} \in \mathcal{O}(n^2)$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, exponentiation

Why, or why not, is $5^{\log_3(n)} \in \mathcal{O}(n^2)$ ?

I tried transforming the logarithm to a base of 5, so that the logarithm and power cancel each other out. However, when I try to so I get

$5^{\log_5(n) \cdot \log_3(5)}$

The $\log_3(5)$ obviously is a constant, but since its a factor of the exponent and not a summand, I don't know how to continue.

Any ideas on how to determine the asymptotic behavior of $5^{\log_3(n)}$?

Comment: A quick tip: $5^{\log_5(n)} = n$.

Comment: Another quick tip: $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$.

Comment: @Indigo That's what I meant with canceling each other out :)

Comment: One final quick tip: $\log_3(5) \leq 2$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Ah, damn, I'm so stupid. The whole thing would then be $n^{log_3(5)}$ then, right?

Comment: Yep. Better write that with curly brackets, though: `$n^{\log_3}(5)$` to get $n^{\log_3}(5)$. (Oh, I see you found that out while I was writing this.) Note the backslash on the log. Also don't use the asterisk $*$ for multiplication outside of programming. In mathematics, it has a different meaning (usually convolution). I edited the question for you.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Alright, thanks for teaching me. I'm quite new to Latex :)

Comment: $5^{\log_3 n} = n^{\log_3 5}$ and $\log_3 5<2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$5^{\log_3(n)}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln n}{\ln 3}\times\ln 5\right)=n^\alpha$$
where $\alpha=\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 3}$
and since
$$\ln 5<\ln 9=2\ln 3\iff\alpha<2$$
then Yes we have

$$5^{\log_3(n)}=n^\alpha=\mathcal O(n^2)$$

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't think of this myself.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: $\alpha = \log_3 5$. Much easier to avoid natural logs and write: $5=3^{\log_3 5}$ so $5^{n} = n^{\log_3 5}$...